# Mule:The difference between the Web Service Consumer and SOAP Connect

Tags: mule, mule-component

Why do we have SOAP connect option while creating a connector when we already have a Web Service Consumer connector? We can configure a wsdl with Web Service Consumer and access a web service. What is the difference between the two options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Why do we have SOAP connect option" because MuleSoft want to provide a method for ISV to provide connectors to new and existing endpoints without Mulesoft themselves having to create them. Mulesoft Anypoint Platform success is built on the premise of connecting to anything and therefore SOAP Connect helps this.

Secondly connecting to a using WSDL location for consuming a soap web service involves a developer to know the service pretty well and therefore allowing error and interpretation errors but if you internally create a connector you can reduce implementation time and errors.

Thirdly on WSDL there are often many methods not applicable or and an enterprise does not want to consume and therefore a connector can filter these methods.

Connectors = Re-Use

Web Service Consumer connector = manual process

Answer (score 0):

The [Web Service Consumer](https://docs.mulesoft.com/getting-started/anypoint-exchange#referencing-a-wsdl-file) is an existing connector that you can configure to point to a WSDL location for consuming a soap web service. [SOAP Connect](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-connector-devkit/v/3.8/creating-a-soap-connector) is a DevKit wizard that creates an Anypoint Connector that connects to a specific service, which can expose multiple WSDLs of the service.

Answer (score 0):

With Web Service Consumer we have to call each API separately in separate flows. With SOAP Connect, you can package multiple WSDL files and API versions into a single connector, making the process of creating, maintaining and using a connector for SOAP APIs much faster and easier.